# What does fetch() fetch in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is a follow up to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061986/is-there-a-way-to-print-the-elements-of-a-list-object-in-python).

I thought that

```
    mylist = list(Rep().all().fetch(50))
```

makes `mylist` a list. But when I try to get its length I get the message

```
self.response.out.write(len(P))
TypeError: object of type 'Rep' has no len()
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
    Rep().replist = L                                   
    Rep().put()                              
    mylist = list(Rep().all().fetch(50))
    P = mylist.pop()
    self.response.out.write(len(P))
```

**UPDATE**

As a reference for others who may encounter the same problem; I post the following table which was very helpful to me. (The original [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/edf12c874e7b2733))

```
Rep().........................Rep object 
Rep.all().....................Query object 
list(Rep.all())...............List of Rep objects. 
list(Rep.all())[0]............A single Rep object 
list(Rep.all())[0].replist....A list
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: P not list. it's a "Rep" instance.

Comment: How do I make it a list so that I can print the elements of replist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Rep().replist = L                                    
Rep().put()                               
mylist = list(Rep().all().fetch(50)) 
P = mylist.pop() 
self.response.out.write(len(P))
```

Try something like this:

```
r = Rep()
r.replist = L                                    
r.put()                               
mylist = Rep.all().fetch(50)
P = mylist.pop() 
self.response.out.write(len(P.replist))
```

This code of yours:

```
Rep().replist = L                                    
Rep().put()
```

Is creating a `Rep` instance, then assigning its `replist` to `L`. Then it's creating another `Rep`, and calling `put()` on it. So the one you are writing to the datastore is a blank `Rep` - it won't have your list.

In this code:

```
mylist = list(Rep().all().fetch(50))
```

You are calling `all()` on an instance of `Rep` - you should instead call it directly on the class. Also you don't need to wrap the results in `list()`, as `fetch()` already returns a list.

Then below where you have this:

```
self.response.out.write(len(P))
```

You are trying to get the length of `P` (which is a `Rep`), not the length of `P`'s `replist`.

**Update:**

*In response to the first comment:*

In this code:

```
r = Rep()
```

The `Rep()` is creating an instance of a `Rep`. The `r =` is then assigning that instance to the name `r`. So now the name `r` refers to that instance of a `Rep`.

Then in this code:

```
r.replist = L
```

It is assigning the replist property of `r` to refer to the list `L`.

You are correct, instead of those two lines you can do this:

```
r = Rep(replist = L)
```

What this does is pass `L` to the `__init__` function of `Rep`, with the argument name `replist`. The `__init__` function of `Rep` is inherited from the `db.Model` base class. This function assigns the value of any arguments provided to a property of the same name on the model. So in this case, it assigns `L` to the `replist` property. So it has the same effect as the original two lines of code, but it works a bit differently.

*In response to the second comment:*

The = operator in Python means assignment, which is not the same as mathematical equivalence.

So this code:

```
r = Rep()
```

Does not mean that `r` is now equivalent to `Rep()`, and that you can now use `r` and `Rep()` to mean the same thing.

What it means is that `r` is now equal to the result of `Rep()`. What `Rep()` does is allocate a new instance of a `Rep`. So that makes `r` a reference to a new `Rep`. To refer to that same instance later, you therefore need to use `r`, not `Rep()` (which would allocate a new instance each time you call it).

Comment: @Saxon Druce: Thanks for this explanation, it was helpful. I am still studying it but do you know if there is an alternative notation to dot notation; eg, I believe that your `r.replist=L` is equivalent to `Rep(replist=L)` Correct? That makes more sense to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Saxon Druce: You are right; the one I was writing to datastore must have been empty because template was printing empty lists. But as far as I can understand your `r.replist = L r.put` is equivalent to mine because you defined r = Rep(). Correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: One additional note: you don't need to wrap the return of .fetch() in a list() - the return value is already a list.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I've updated my answer to mention that list() is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.response.out.write(len(mylist))
```

Comment: len(mylist) returns the number of lists in mylist. I assume that P = mylist.pop() would pop the last list in mylist. And I want to print the elements of that popped list. But as DonaldlsFreak mentions what is popped is not a list but a "Rep" instance. Sorry, I don't understand why the list L I saved to datastore is not returning. Or what is the best way to do this simple database operation? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the number of elements of **replist property**.

```
self.response.write(len(P.replist));
```

*Hope i can help you :p*